# Music theory books

Tags: theory

I want to start reading books about harmony, scales, modes, etc. I'm a beginner in theory - I started learning on musictheoryacademy.com, so I want to start expanding my knowledge after finishing the material on this website. I like listening to Jacob Collier's takes on harmony and such, but does anyone know of any books that someone with his knowledge might have read? I know the basics, I'm just ready to expand, I think. All suggestions are welcome, seriously, I love music.

Answer (score 1):

You might get down-voted to close for asking an opinion based question or requesting resources, but it seem pointless to not recommend some basic, well known texts.

- Kostka & Payne, Tonal Harmony. A well known college textbook.
- Piston, Harmony. Another seminal text.

Less well known, but a personal favorite...

- Siegmeister, Harmony and Melody. This doesn't seem to be used as a course textbook, but I really like the wide range of musical styles it includes in examples.

For counterpoint Mann's translation of Fux

- The Study of Counterpoint: From Johann Joseph Fux's Gradus Ad Parnassum